# Core Data Integer changing value?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

i have a problem with core data storing integer (i chose int16 because they have a maximum of 6 signs).

my model holds

```
Entity: 'Expense'
the attribute in question is:


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * month;
```

it was automatically implemented as NSNumber by Xcode (Editor > createManagedmodelsubclass)

month holds an short identifier for every month. example

```
201203     //would be march of 2012
```

i store new entities with this snippet:

```
[newExpense setValue:monthNumber forKey:@"month"];
```

which works just fine. monthNumber has always the right value before i store it.

i retrieve objects with a fetching method and store them in an array called `allExpenses`. the array count is true and i have the right amount of entities in it.

now i do this:

```
NSMutableArray *thisMonthExpenses = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];

for (Expense *entity in allExpenses) {
    int tempMonth = [[entity month]intValue];
    if (tempMonth == month) {
        [thisMonthExpenses addObject:entity];

    }
}
```

to filter out the right entities that belong to the current month.

```
month // is an integer that holds the encoded month (again: correctly!)
```

but somehow the code:

```
int tempMonth = [[entity month]intValue];
```

does not return 201203, but strangly 4595  (always the same value).

the same happens with this code:

```
for (Expense *entity in monthExpenses) {
    if ([entity day].intValue == todayNumber.intValue) { //HERE ENTITY DAY.INTVALUE RETURNS A COMPLETELY WRONG INTEGER!
        [thisDayExpenses addObject:entity];
    }
}
```

i seem to be missing something - but i cannot figure out what, i tried around for 2 hours now and always get the wrong int value after reading my entities..

any ideas?

Comment: Is monthNumber definitely an NSNumber when you're assigning that value to your managed object? You don't show the origin, perhaps it needs to be boxed?

Comment: For example: [newExpense setMonth:[NSNumber numberWithInt:monthNumber]];

Comment: i've tried that as well @isaac. but it does not make any difference. i still get a wrong int returned when trying to check it :/

Comment: i added a CAPS comment to the last code snipped to show you again what goes wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

201203 is 0x311F3, while 4595 is 0x11F3 — so what's happening is, you're losing the most significant byte. It sounds like in CoreData you have the number set as a 16-bit integer, which isn't capable of storing the number you want (16 bits can only represent up to the low five digits in decimal). It should be a 32-bit integer.

Comment: that sounds promising - i'll give it a try tomorrow (its 1'30am here now) il up accept your answer of course if it works =)

Comment: works now - thanks a lot, sometimes the answer is too close to see ;-)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
Expense.month = monthNumber;
```

or

```
[Expense setMonth:monthNumber];
```

Comment: i dont want to set the monthNumber. i want to retrieve it.

Comment: and i can retrieve it. but i dont get the value that should be there.

Comment: Why do you think this would make a difference? I'd think this is precisely what Sebastian's original code would do under the hood.