# Integer store value is negative

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a Core Data model that contains an `id` field which is a **Integer 16**.

I noticed that the app was saving some object with a negative value in that field

For instance (from sqlite3 command line):

```
2|1|1|-32223||9|424968994|424968994|step`
```

I thought I'd switch to **Integer 32** in order to fix it but the problem still remains. Object are still saved with a negative value in that field. I'm not quite sure why.

Was that right to switch to **Integer 32**? Should have this fixed the problem?

Edit: Example of value I want to save

For example the value I am storing is **33239** but it's saved as **-32297**

Comment: What values are you saving to that field?  The Core Data integer types are signed, so it's allowed for them to have negative values.

Comment: once check thi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610592/core-data-integer-changing-value

Comment: Are you sure your app is using the Integer 32 column?  Try deleting the app, deleting your derived data, and running a clean build.

Comment: I already tried deleting the app and reinstalling it but without deleting the derived data. Will try that. Is there any way I can check if the app is using Integer 32?

Comment: I tried deleting everything but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Sunny: I'm already using Integer 32 in my Core Data Entity. Is there anything else I would need to change in the code.

Comment: What is the value you're storing there???

Comment: See the edit.  I am storing is 33239 but it's saved as -32297

Answer (score 1):

Being `unsigned long` compatible with `Integer32` and `Integer64`, you should pass this type of var (`unsigned long`) to save in `CoreData`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue.I am storing the 33675 integer value in `CoreData` but when i retrieve i got value like -26532.

In My case i defined my integer value as type `int16` so range of `int16` is **-32,768 to 32,767** when i change my variable from `int16` to `int64` its resolved my issue.

for reference :[Swift - Data Types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_data_types.htm)
[image]